# Overlay layer without interactivity in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, overlay, interaction

Recently Xamarin.Forms changed its behavior for controls with `Clear` and `Default` background. The changes are described in this PR: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/935

This change was quite a breaking change in two of my apps. The default XAML behavior in UWP and WPF is that when `Background` is clear (`x:Null`), the visual is click-through, but If it has some children, you can still interact with them. This is very important especially for mapping apps where you often need map control and then layout some control above it. If I set the layer to `InputTransparent` user cannot interact with any controls in the layer in any way, if I don't set it, then I cannot interact with the map itself.

The problem is that I don't see any easy workaround to this, because I cannot layout the controls without a layout parent. If I want to lay them out in a grid, I need a Grid above them. and that will block the map. Same with any other layout.

I want to achieve something like the following:

```
<CustomMapControl />
<Grid x:Name="ControlsGrid">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="Zoom in" />
</Grid>
<AboluteLayout x:Name="PlaceMenuContainer" />
```

This code now will not allow me to interact with the map, because the Grid occludes it. If I add `InputTransparent="True"` to the Grid, I cannot interact with the button anymore, as the touch interactions are no longer dispatched to them (see [VisualInputRenderer, line 52 - 64](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/e32f96e97ac4b3a8d067d502c31ad67dd9d7d54d/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/VisualElementRenderer.cs)). Also note that I can have multiple layers above the map, like the `PlaceMenuContainer` which is a container for context menu items which are displayed above the map when the user taps a certain location on the map. This means I cannot easily use a single layout container for all controls...

Do you see any way around this?

Comment: Hi Martin. I think you'll have more answers (specially from the Xamarin team) if you create a simple repro-project showing what you're trying to achieve. Personally not sure I understand what you want to do and an example would help. You could make one commit where it's working with your current Xamarin.Forms version, and then one commit where you update the Xamarin.Forms version?

Comment: Yes, I will try to provide a sample repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a confirmation from E. Z. Hart from the Microsoft Xamarin Team that this issue is currently looked at, and that several developers have run into this problem. Either a workaround of a new approach will be implemented soon, any updates will be posted on the related [bug in Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60766) :-).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <CustomMapControl Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
   <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="Click me" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not a feasible solution for me. In the real app I have several layers on top and I cannot use one layout for all controls. Concretely, I have a layer of "context menus" that are above the map and are created as the user taps different places on the map. So I need a `AbsoluteLayout`, while for some controls I need the `Grid` (for example zoom buttons)

Comment: I see. I had a similar problem I think. You need to set the grid HorizontalOptions and Vertical options not to expand (start, end, center for example).

Comment: That would work for zoom buttons for example, but not in case I need an overlay layer for context menus / etc. :-( ...

Comment: You need to interact with both the overlay and the layer below?

Comment: Yes, that is the case. I need to be able to move the map and drag the overlay menus as well